# How to change users html form input and add a \ infront of evrey '

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, textarea

This might seem complecated.

I have a html form that lets the user upload python code. When submitted the python code is located in a textarea on a brand new page, for example:

```
<textarea id='yourcode' cols='40' rows='10'>
<?php echo 'inch = 1 
centimeter = 2.54 
inch1 = float(raw_input('Enter the value in inches 
that you want to convert. ')) 
print "A value of %r inches is equal to %r centimeters." 
% (inch1,inch1 * inch * centimeter) '; ?>
</textarea>
```

As you can see, the pythons ' interacts with the php ' and causes an error. Is there anyway to automaticly read through the insert and add a \ so that the ' in the python  doesnt interact. It would change the code above(which doesnt work) into

```
<textarea id='yourcode' cols='40' rows='10'>
<?php echo 'inch = 1 
centimeter = 2.54 
inch1 = float(raw_input(\'Enter the value in inches 
that you want to convert. \')) 
print "A value of %r inches is equal to %r centimeters." 
% (inch1,inch1 * inch * centimeter) '; ?>
</textarea>
```

And this above will work. Sorry if this is complectaed and ask if you have a question. Does anybody have any idea how to create this script that automaticly adds a \ infront of the users input of python code which might contain a ' that ruins the script. Thanks

Comment: How is the python in the PHP? Shouldn't it be in a variable?

Comment: The javascript that interprets the python code doesnt work if it is an php echo vairable

Comment: use `addslashes` on the posted code and then echo it back.

Comment: Im not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python code embedded in PHP code, use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in PHP:

```
<textarea id='yourcode' cols='40' rows='10'>
<?php $text = <<<EOT
    inch = 1 
    centimeter = 2.54 
    inch1 = float(raw_input('Enter the value in inches 
      that you want to convert. ')) 
    print "A value of %r inches is equal to %r centimeters." 
      % (inch1,inch1 * inch * centimeter)
EOT; 
echo $text; ?>
</textarea>
```

Even simpler, without an intermediary variable:

```
<textarea id='yourcode' cols='40' rows='10'>
<?php echo <<<EOT
    inch = 1
    centimeter = 2.54
    inch1 = float(raw_input('Enter the value in inches
      that you want to convert. '))
    print "A value of %r inches is equal to %r centimeters."
      % (inch1,inch1 * inch * centimeter)
EOT; ?>
</textarea>
```

A safer version using [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to prevent harmful HTML code:

```
<textarea id='yourcode' cols='40' rows='10'>
<?php echo filter_var( <<<EOT
    inch = 1
    centimeter = 2.54
    inch1 = float(raw_input('Enter the value in inches
      that you want to convert. '))
    print "A value of %r inches is equal to %r centimeters."
      % (inch1,inch1 * inch * centimeter)
EOT
    , FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS ?>
</textarea>
```

A heredoc needn't be escaped. There are some security issues however. But the real question is: how do you get the user input string from your form?

Comment: hello there. The user can upload any python code to my website, it fwrites a new page with that code on, then i have a javascript python intrpeter that runs the code on site

Comment: May I ask why you went that way? There are various ways to achieve what you want so I assume you've gone round the question and found out what fits best. Just curious.

Comment: Hello, my website i am making is here: http://mathswiki.org/submit/submit.php and the code section is where you insert some code.

Comment: If you add some code with just ", however if you insert some python code with ' it throws an error

Comment: You will of course have to manage erratic inputs to prevent your PHP code to throw exceptions. A heredoc spares you the burden of escaping a string but it doesn't guarantee it's valid input. You will need to check that, too, especially given that it could contain potentially harmful `<script>` tags.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: See my updated response. It's ugly, right but for the sake of the example... Make it less ugly by defining a function with only one argument that wraps the call to `filter_var()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
addslashes($thePythonTextYouWantToAdd\)
```

Comment: Please explain your answers. Else people will downvote.